# Error when try to add Google Maps

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, android-maps

Couple moths ago i testing this app on Android N and all will work correctly, but now i have error. Now i'am using MapFragment and have this error:

```
05-09 23:22:35.816 11112-11112/pc.dd.sex_startup E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: pc.dd.sex_startup, PID: 11112
                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pc.dd.sex_startup/pc.dd.sex_startup.LogIn.Maps.Map}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2423)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
                                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                   at pc.dd.sex_startup.LogIn.Maps.Map.onCreate(Map.java:85)
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628) 
                                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:786)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                   at pc.dd.sex_startup.LogIn.Maps.Map.onCreate(Map.java:85) 
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303) 
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628) 
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Configuration android.content.res.Resources.getConfiguration()' on a null object reference
                                                                   at android.util.ResolutionOverride.<init>(ResolutionOverride.java:56)
                                                                   at android.view.SurfaceView.init(SurfaceView.java:207)
                                                                   at android.view.SurfaceView.<init>(SurfaceView.java:187)
                                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.an.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:231)
                                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.ai.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:163)
                                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.ao.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:389)
                                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.ao.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:349)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.eb.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:4048)
                                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.az.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:403)
                                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.az.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:320)
                                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.cp.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82)
                                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.co.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:139)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.w.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:107)
                                                                   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
```

and in java:

```
public class Map extends AppCompatActivity  implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private MapView mapView;
private GoogleMap map;
private android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
private FragmentImage fragment;
public ClusterManager<MyItem> mClusterManager;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_main);

    //add status bar
    statusBarFragment status_bar = new statusBarFragment();
    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.statbar_container_map, status_bar)
            .commit();

    // Get the map and register for the ready callback.
    MapFragment mapFragment = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

and xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/statbar_container_map">

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

also try to change `AppCompatActivity` to `FragmentActivity`. Before that i'am using `SupportMapFragment` and have same error. What wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I also experience the same(which was no problem previously). Workaround is to add following flag to your **`MapActivity`** in your *`AndroidManifest.xml`* file

`android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`

Comment: Good to hear it works. If you have too many activities you can add it to <application> tag, too.

Comment: What is "old SDK"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I tried to mean it if the app was supporting older API, it was OK and the problems started happen with recent API.

Comment: Hi, actually i don't understand. hardwareAccelerated default value is true in application tag , so why i should write there ? thanks.

Comment: why this "solves" the problem?