# java.lang.RuntimeException: createContext failed: 12291 on real devices

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-utils

on crashlytic dashboard I can see lots of crashes on various devices - samsung, motorola, sony etc operating system - Android 4, 5, 6.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
createContext failed: 12291

com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.ba.a
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.ba.a (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14799008@14.7.99 (000306-223214910):22)
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bb.run (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14799008@14.7.99 (000306-223214910):161)
```

note - These are real devices not emulator, where I can change setting to Software GLES 2.0 .

Comment: Look at [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44380686/3800164) may help you

Comment: @android_griezmann Hardware acceleration is enabled by default if your Target API level is >=14